# Command line argument in C causing segmentaion fault?

Tags: java, c, string, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

*I want to write a simple program to print the command line argument we pass to it back to the terminal*

I usually program in Java, where its perfectly acceptable to write

```
public class cmdargs
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
if(args.length>0)
System.out.println(args[0]);
}
}//class ends
```

Now in `C` the closest thing to a `String` I could find is a `char[]` or rather `char name[]`

So when i write

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(char args[])
{
printf("%s",args);
return 0;
}
```

Why am i getting a segmentation fault?

```
./cmdargs hi
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Note:  **java != C**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because this signature is wrong

```
int main(char args[])
```

in c, the number of arguments is passed as the first argument, and the arguments are passed as an array of pointers, so the correct signature should be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

and then you can access the values, for example

```
int i;

for (i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
```

please enable compiler warnings, to prevent this kind of program from compiling.

Comment: Thanks but why use char *argv[] instead of just char argv[], to enable recieving many args i suppose , (Sorry i suck at pointers)

Comment: `char argv[]` is an array of `char`. `char` represents a single character not a string, the concept of string in c is quite different from that of Java. `char *argv[]` is an array of char pointers, which could actually also be written as `char **argv`. A char pointer, is a pointer to data of `char` type, the are considered a string when the consist of a sequence of bytes terminated by a `'\0'` byte.

Comment: Thanks i changed to` int main(int arg, char *args[]) 
{
printf("%s",args[0]);   `                                                                                             
`./cmdargs hello`                        Does not print anything?

Comment: It should print the program name. Even if you don't pass anyarguments to the program, that should work. Can you please tell me if you are using any particular IDE or something like that.

Comment: No just vi in Ubuntu and running from the terminal

Comment: @DroidIcs: Try `printf ("%s\n", args[0]);`.Some C libraries/command interpreters will not output lines on `stdout` that do not end with a **newline**, and are not required to do so by the C language.